# Json Data converted to Json string but not in Json Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

This question has been asked so many times but using the same code I am getting things work.

I have used below code to generate Json Dictionary and Json string.It successfully creates json string but not json dictionary.

```
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

 NSString *strJsonRequest = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSDictionary *dicJsonRequest = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&convertError];

NSLog(@"\n dicjson : %@ \n json string : %@ \n error : %@",dicJsonRequest,strJsonRequest,convertError.localizedDescription);
```

This metods I am using to pass data and this needs NSDictionary

```
- (void)postPath:(NSString *)path
      parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

If I create NSDictionary using JsonString created here then it gets converted to different format that is not being accepted at webservice end

```
NSDictionary *WSCALL = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strJsonRequest,"Post", nil];
 NSLog(@"WSCALL : %@",WSCALL);
```

output :

```
WSCALL : {
    Post = "{\n  \"email\" : \"test@test.com\",\n  \"password\" : \"test\",\n  \"name\" : \"abcd\",\n ";
}
```

**EDIT**

What i can conclude here is webservice needs the same json string created but without this "\n" and \"email\" (FALSE) -> "email"(TRUE)
But i am not able to replace "\n" because it is adding when i set value for key in dictionary.

With this I am getting output as

```
dicjson : {
    email = "test@test.com";
    name = abcd;
    password = test;
} 
 json string : {
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "name" : "abcd",
  "password" : "test"
} 
 error : (null)
```

Comment: Where is the problem? You get a dictionary, a string, and no error. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My problem is I am not getting dictionary in json format.Even though I can get a string into json but for my requirement i need json dictionary

Comment: I am using ASIHTTP where it needs NSDictionary as request parameter and in webservice I need to pass structure created in json string. I have checked json string directly to REST then it is working but data type in code is not working

Comment: Can't it be like using ":" instead of "=" ?

Comment: What happens if you do... `NSLog(@"%@", dicJsonRequest[@"email"]);`?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is **no error in what you are doing** and the log says clearly you are getting a NSDictionary, and If you try to log an NSDictionary it is obvious you get a json string response.See this line

```
NSLog(@"\n dicjson : %@ \n json string : %@ \n error : %@",dicJsonRequest,strJsonRequest,convertError.localizedDescription);
```

Here the NDDictionary contains the value correctly since the log shows

```
dicjson : {
    email = "test@test.com";
    name = abcd;
    password = test;
}
```

So you have a valid dictionary in hand.Just do the remaining coding

Comment: It expects the json string format for Dictionary I am getting.like ":" instead of "="

Comment: I am not getting why if I set string to dictionary it becomes  `Post = "{\n  \"email\" : \"test@test.com\",\n  \"password\" : \"test\",\n  \"name\" : \"abcd\",\n ";` and after that if i get as `valueforkey:@"Post"` it prints normal string `{"email" : "test@test.com",
  "name" : "abcd",
  "password" : "test"}`